# How to make shift register logisim

Tags: led, digital-logic, flipflop, shift-register, logisim

How would I make a 4-bit shift register with D flip flops so that only 1 LED is active at once. So for example if a button was pushed the first LED would light up and the other 3 would be off. If the button was pushed again the second led would light up and the other 3 would be off etc. I want to be able to do this with 4 LEDs.

This is what I've tried but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. Any help is appreciated as I've just started to learn.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGfvc4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: the LED part and resistor values were just the defaults when dropped onto the schematic. They would likely need adjustment in a real circuit.

Or here it is in [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+14.235633750745258+52+5+43%0A155+-32+192+112+192+0+0%0A155+288+192+432+192+0+0%0A155+128+192+384+192+0+0%0A155+448+192+592+192+0+0%0A153+64+96+-80+96+0+3+0+5%0Aw+64+112+80+112+0%0Aw+64+96+240+96+0%0Aw+240+96+240+192+0%0Aw+64+80+400+80+0%0Aw+400+80+400+192+0%0Aw+-80+96+-80+192+0%0Aw+-80+192+-32+192+0%0Aw+-80+304+-64+304+0%0Aw+-80+304+-80+224+0%0Aw+-80+224+-32+224+0%0Aw+80+112+80+192+0%0Aw+80+192+64+192+0%0Aw+80+192+112+192+0%0Aw+128+192+112+192+0%0Aw+240+192+224+192+0%0Aw+240+192+272+192+0%0Aw+288+192+272+192+0%0Aw+400+192+384+192+0%0Aw+400+192+432+192+0%0Aw+448+192+432+192+0%0AR+-80+224+-144+224+1+2+100+2.5+2.5+0+0.5%0Ar+80+416+80+512+0+220%0Ar+240+416+240+512+0+220%0Ar+400+416+400+512+0+220%0A162+80+320+80+416+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ag+320+512+320+560+0%0Ar+576+416+576+512+0+220%0Aw+80+320+80+192+0%0A162+240+320+240+416+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+400+320+400+416+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0A162+576+320+576+416+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+240+320+240+192+0%0Aw+400+320+400+192+0%0Aw+576+320+576+192+0%0Aw+576+192+544+192+0%0Aw+80+512+240+512+0%0Aw+240+512+320+512+0%0Aw+400+512+320+512+0%0Aw+576+512+400+512+0%0Aw+-64+304+128+304+0%0Aw+128+304+128+224+0%0Aw+128+304+288+304+0%0Aw+288+304+288+224+0%0Aw+288+304+448+304+0%0Aw+448+304+448+224+0%0A), so you can see the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of shift registers:

**First: *Series in Series out* (SISO)**

[image]

**Second: *Series in Parallel out* (SIPO)**

[image]

I used a button in Logisim as a manual clock .